Evaluate the following complex integral
Evaluate the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{i r \cos\theta}\cos(i r \sin\theta-n\theta)  d\theta$$
where n is an positive integer and r is a positive real number.

I've tried two approaches but it turned out to be two different results.
First approach:
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{i r \cos\theta}\cos(i r \sin\theta-n\theta)  d\theta &= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{{e^{ir(\frac{\pi}2+\theta)}e^{-in\theta}}}{2}+\frac{{e^{ir(\frac{\pi}2-\theta)}e^{in\theta}}}{2} d\theta
\\ &= e^{ir\frac{\pi}2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{{e^{ir\theta}e^{-in\theta}}+e^{-ir\theta}e^{in\theta}}{2} d\theta
\\ &= e^{ir\frac{\pi}2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos{((r-n)\theta)} d\theta
\\ &=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{e^{ir\frac{\pi}2}}{r-n}\sin(2r\pi) &r\neq n \\
2\pi e^{ir\frac{\pi}2} &r = n
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}$$
Second approach(forming a complex contour integral):
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{i r \cos\theta}\cos(i r \sin\theta-n\theta)  d\theta &=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{{e^{ir\cos\theta-r\sin\theta}e^{-in\theta}}+e^{ir\cos\theta-r\sin\theta}e^{in\theta}}{2} d\theta
\\&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{{e^{ire^{i\theta}}e^{-in\theta}}+e^{ire^{-i\theta}}e^{in\theta}}{2} d\theta
\\& \boxed{\begin{aligned}
               z &= e^{i\theta},\\ 
              dz &= ie^{i\theta} d\theta
          \end{aligned}} 
\\&=-\frac{i}2\oint_C\frac{{e^{irz}}}{z^{n+1}} dz +\frac{i}{2}\oint_{-C}\frac{{e^{irz}}}{z^{n+1}}  dz \qquad\text{(where C is the unit circle)}\ 
\\&=-\frac{i}2 \frac{2\pi i}{n!} (ir)^{n} + -\frac{i}2 \frac{2\pi i}{n!} (ir)^{n} \qquad \text{(by Cauchy's integral formula)}\
\\&= \frac{2\pi}{n!}r^ni^n
\end{align*}$$
Why are there two different answers?

How did you get the first line?

I used Euler’s formula to substitute $\cos(ir\sin\theta-n\theta)$

Note
$$ \cos(ir\sinθ−nθ)=\frac12\bigg[e^{i(ir\sinθ−nθ)}+e^{-i(ir\sinθ−nθ)}\bigg]$$
and hence
$$\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int^{2π}_0 e^{ir\cos θ}\cos(ir\sinθ−nθ)dθ\\
&=&\frac12\int^{2π}_0 e^{ir\cos θ}\bigg[e^{i(ir\sinθ−nθ)}+e^{-i(ir\sinθ−nθ)}\bigg]dθ\\
&=&\frac12\int^{2π}_0 \bigg[e^{i(ir\sinθ−nθ)+ir\cos θ}+e^{-i(ir\sinθ−nθ)+ir\cos θ}\bigg]dθ\\
&=&\frac12\int^{2π}_0 \bigg[e^{ir(\cos θ+i\sin\theta)-n\theta i}+e^{-ir(\cos θ-i\sin\theta)+n\theta i}\bigg]dθ\\
&=&\frac12\int^{2π}_0 \bigg[e^{ir(\cos θ+i\sin\theta)}e^{-n\theta i}+e^{-ir(\cos θ-i\sin\theta)}e^{n\theta i}\bigg]dθ\\
&\overset{e^{i\theta}=z}
=&\frac12\int_{|z|=1}\bigg[e^{irz}z^{-n}+e^{-ir\frac1z}z^{n}\bigg]\frac{dz}{iz}\\
&=&\frac1{2i}\int_{|z|=1}\bigg[\frac{e^{irz}}{z^{n+1}}+e^{-ir\frac1z}z^{n-1}\bigg]dz\\
&=&\frac1{2i}\cdot2\pi i\bigg[\frac{(ir)^n}{n!}+\frac{(-ir)^n}{n!}\bigg]=\frac{2\pi}{n!}\Re(ir)^n.
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$
\begin{aligned} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{ir\cos\theta} \cos(ir\sin \theta-n \theta) d \theta 
& =\Re \int_0^{2\pi} e^{ir\cos \theta} e^{i(ir\sin \theta-n \theta)} d \theta \\
&=\Re \int_0^{2 \pi} e^{i r(\cos \theta+i \sin \theta)-in \theta} d \theta \\
& =\Re \oint_{|z|=1} e^{irz} z^{-n} \frac{d z}{i z}, \quad \textrm{ where }z=e^{i\theta}\\
& =\Re\left[\frac{1}{i} \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{e^{i r z}}{z^{n+1}} d z\right] \\
& =\Re\left[\frac{1}{i} \cdot 2 \pi i \cdot \frac{1}{n!}\left[z^{n+1} \cdot \frac{e^{irz}}{z^{n+1}}\right]^{(n)} \right]_{z=0} \\&=\frac{2 \pi}{n!} \Re(i r)^n
\end{aligned}
$$
